# popular dentro da textarea do mysql para o formulário

Tags: php, javascript

```
public function geraFormTipo1(){

    return
<<<EOT

        <div class="questao-{$this->objQuestoes->numQuestao()}" {$this->isHide}>
            {$this->label()}
            <table class="table tabela-modelo-1">
            {$this->estruturaMain()}
            </table>
            Justifique sua resposta
            <textarea  name="resposta{$this->objQuestoes->numQuestao()}"><?php echo \$resposta{$this->objQuestoes->numQuestao()} ?></textarea>
        </div>


EOT;
}
```

Dei um `echo` na string de retorno do método `geraFormTipo1()` e imprimi no `HTML`. 
Quando acessei o html após a impressão, percebi que dentro da `textarea` ficou populada como: `<?php $respostaA ?>`. A intenção era que futuramente eu iria popular os dados do banco para o `html`, ou seja a variável que era pra ser de retorno (do banco para o html) está sendo impressa no `textarea`, o que é errado.

o que devo fazer para consertar o meu código?

por exemplo:
mandei printar dentro do index.php

```
$formulario = $new Questionario($objQuestoes);
$formHTML = $formulario->geraFormTipo1();

echo formHTML;



<textarea name="respostaA"><?php $respostaA ?></textarea>
```

- iria popular do banco para o html futuramente.
- o campo texto da minha textarea está printando `<?php $respostaA ?>`

Comment: o seu arquivo tem a extensão php? Você está usando alguma framework? Qual o seu servidor, `Apache` ou `php -S`?

Comment: não estou usando framework e a extensão está em php. estou usando apache.

Comment: Está usando xampp no Windows ou instalação manual (LAMP)?

Comment: estou usando xampp no windows. tentei hospedar no site, e deu a mesma coisa, as tags estão sendo printadas na textarea

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma, talvez eu tenha digitado algo errado, não testei, mas da pra entender a ideia

return"
    objQuestoes->numQuestao()}' {$this->isHide}>
            {$this->label()} 
            
            {$this->estruturaMain()}
             
            Justifique sua resposta 
            objQuestoes->numQuestao()}'>Resposta
{$this->objQuestoes->numQuestao()}
            
        ";